# When I try to run Python script on any editor or cmd I get this error

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

on editor Sublime Text 3, visual studio code, notepad++ or cmd the same problem

```
C:\Users\Egypt>python Desktop/python/any file.py
```

when i try run any file i get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/python/reqweb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 28, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 22, in <module>
    import bz2
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\bz2.py", line 18, in <module>
    from threading import RLock
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 7, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tokenize.py", line 34, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\Desktop\python\token.py", line 1, in <module>
    import facebook
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    _lock = threading.RLock()
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'RLock'
```

please help i try uninstall python and reinstall But the same problem
this error Appears only in scripts inside import models

Comment: Please post your code. We cannot begin to help otherwise.

Comment: Does this happen when you just try and enter the Python interpreter (I.e when you just type "Python" with no argument?). Otherwise it's this a bug in a specific Python module you're trying to execute?

Comment: every code inside import some models

Comment: I think there is an error with the import in   File "C:\Users\Egypt\Desktop\python\token.py", line 1, in <module>

Comment: thanks.. i delete this file and error disapear

Answer (score 1):

I realize the comment above more or less resolved the issue, but to explain what was actually happening (because I just had a very similar problem and found this question):

It looks like your file `C:\Users\Egypt\Desktop\python\token.py` was incorrectly being picked as the source for the `from token import *` statement in the system's `C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tokenize.py` module.  It was actually intending to reference the module `C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\token.py`. Since your version of the file wasn't what it expected, it raised an exception.

Either of these fixes should work in this case:

1. Rename your token.py file to a non-conflicting name
2. Don't execute python from this folder as the current directory.